# How to select this in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
<div>
 <h3>Hello World</h3>
 <p>Hello</p>
 <ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

My question would be, if I clicked on `<h3>Hello World</h3>`
How can I let something happen to the ul in **this** div, so not in a other div?

Is the ul a sibling from h3 or child?

```
$(h3).clicked(function(){
 $(this).???.slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Siblings with jquery:

```
   $('h3').on('click', function(){
     $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('h3').click(
        function(event)
       { 
            $(event.target).parent().find('ul li').slideDown();
       }
    );
```

You have to use `on` if ul and li are dynamic elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... I couldn't get it to animate, although I added the alerts via selectors as per your possible requirement.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('body div').each(function(){
 H3div = $(this);
 $('h3', H3div).on('click', function(){
      var demo_alert = $('ul', H3div).text();
      alert(demo_alert);
 });
 });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div>
 <h3>Hello World</h3>
 <p>Hello</p>
 <ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/) and [first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/) to target the ul in question.

```
$('h3').on('click', function() {
   $(this).nextAll('ul').first().slideDown();
});
```

`ul` here is a sibling of `h3` element as they are at the same level of hierarchy.